# Are the other wizard arcane traditions not part of the SRD?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, ogl

The 5e SRD mentions all eight schools as possible for the wizard's Arcane Tradition feature.

But later on it only describes evocation.

Does this mean the other seven (as described in the PHB) are not open per the SRD licence?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the details of the other traditions are not licensed under the OGL. The presence or absence of something in the SRD is the literal definition of what parts of D&D 5e have been licensed under the OGL (SRD 5.0 v1.1, p. 1, ¶ 2):

> This material is being released using the Open Gaming License Version 1.0a

If it's not in the SRD, it's not open.

Comment: I had a curiosity about this that doesn't warrant it's own question.  This is causing some complications on R20 using the SRD.  My curiosity was, ARE they going to eventually license/release more content?  Or is this pretty much it...forever...for the OGL SRD?

Comment: @Airatome The purpose of an SRD is to provide *publishers* with reusable content, so that they can include official material in adventures, supplements, etc. where it's logically useful or necessary. It's deliberately not made to be useful to players as a “free” version of the game, since players are not the intended audience for the document. So short answer: no, WotC are not likely to ever release more of the PHB/DMG/MM as OGL, because publishers don't need more.

Comment: ssd this comment is very important (IMHO), add it to the answer body.

Comment: @Mindwin It's answering a different question. If it's that important, the question should be posted as a question. :) Or, if it answers something you had in mind when you were posting your question, that “something” should maybe be added to the question first.

Comment: I was thinking of asking (as communtiy wiki) "If content from the PHB was left out of the SRD, does it mean it is not under the OGL?" And marking this one and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73124/missing-class-and-race-options-in-5th-edition-srd?rq=1 into as dupes. Making a default dupe target for these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Mindwin There's probably no point to making it a CW, since the only point of that is making it more easily editable and there's no obvious reason it would benefit from that. Beyond that, you could, but it would be up to the community to decide which are a duplicate of which, so if you do, make a convincing case for the newer one being a good, clean, canonical question that would make the best master question. :)

Comment: @Mindwin (If you're thinking about it but could use some feedback or have some details you want to ask about, consider whether [meta] might be able to help out.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie posted http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88838/11402 - once it has an answer, i'll dupe-flag this question. Feel free to edit the Q and community-wikify it