# Is the list of weapons and armors in the PHB exhaustive?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, armor

My questions are:

- Are there any other weapons outside of those listed in the ranged and melee weapon tables?
- Are there other types of damage not listed in those weapon tables?

For example: Can a player find an epic sword that would give him +3 strength with insane attack after killing an important enemy, or are weapon drops limited just to the weapons/armor listed in the Players guide?

The reason I ask is that I am making an android app that would allow you to keep information about your character and edit it at any time so you don't have to use a paper/pdf sheet.  I am trying to determine whether to allow users of my app to create their own custom weapons and armor.

I know this is a game of imagination, so the question might be more of an "is it a good idea to make this functionality in my app?"

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this: **Also, do you think there are other types of damage outside mentioned table?**  p. 75 of the Basic Rules list 13 types of damage under the heading "Damage Types" ... but what you are asking is unclear.

Comment: I don't know how much research you've made, but there are a few apps out there that already do this. The one I use is the Fifth Edition Character Sheet, by Walter Kammerer. This app has the option to add custom weapons to their "sheets", so if your goal is to make an app that can compete with already existing solutions, I would highly suggest you implement the feature. If you want to take it a step further, you can allow for creation of weapon and armor presets (storing them separately from a sheet), and sharing them between devices (so a DM can give a weapon to a player digitally)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short Answer: **Yes! There is a number of other items, look at the DMG in specific regards to treasure. As well, the damage sources are listed on page 75 (Basic Rules) under the heading "Damage Types".**

In the DMG *(Chapter 7, Page 133)* there is specific tables for rolling random magical treasure. These tables include Weapon/Armor of various types, including the Weapon+3/etc. Pretty much the entire chapter is full of equipment.

As per the comments, you may also want to look into the extended campaigns as they will make mention to other items not listed in the PHB or DMG. One such example is the Elemental Evil book. Note that some of these items may be campaign-specific and not good for general use.

You may also be interested in the end of the DMG (Chapter 9, Page 284). It has rules for creating new magical items. I assume this may be something of interest in regards to your app (maybe).

Comment: Thank you ! My entire research was based on Players guide so this migt be very helpful.

Comment: There are also adventure-specific magic weapons in the Elemental Evil campaign

Comment: Good point @New_DM_Tryingtobesneaky. I havent used any of the other books/campaigns but I'll make a reference in my answer.

Comment: Which of the 4 questions in the OP does "Yes" refer to?

Comment: I agree with @DaleM, this answer is very confusing. I read the question's title: "Is the list of weapons and armors in the PHB exhaustive?" and then the first accepted answer begins with "Short Answer: Yes!" to which I thought, that can't be right...

Comment: Plus there's nothing stopping GMs and published adventurers from introducing new items of all sorts.

Comment: I'll just address all the comments at once. I answered the question in the post, not the title. "Are there any other weapons outside of those listed in the ranged and melee weapon tables?". As for the second question, that is answered in the comments section. I'll update my answer to add a second part to include that I guess. As for the published adventures, although not explicit I figured that the OP was going for official D&D although I could be wrong. I assume this is still covered by the DMG Chapter 9 involving creating items.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr When it's unclear which question a “Yes!” or “No!” is answering, the easiest fix is to edit to make it a sentence, like “Yes, bionic hamsters can eat granite!” That way, the reader doesn't have to guess (or worse, check the comments) to understand the answer.

Answer (score 6):

As Sh4dowsPlyr has said, there are many Magical Items found throughout all of the material, including Manuals, Campaigns, and the SRD. I would recommend adding the ones from the SRD. For the rest, I'd be careful of copyright issues as they come from copyrighted material. Maybe send an email to Wizards of the Coast before publishing an app with those added in to make sure you won't get any legal issues.

You can find information about D&D 5e copyright issues here - [Is there a OGL or GSL license for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45024/is-there-a-ogl-or-gsl-license-for-dd-5e)

I would also recommend allowing players to add custom equipment, though, as many DMs (including mine) like to give custom equipment to players.